# how to show a message in Facebook with Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have the Facebook sdk integrated in my Android application and whenever I press the a button I want to be able to post a particular message (given by code) to be shown on the user's wall. I have written the following code up till now :

```
public void showFacebookDialog(String message) {
    // post on user's wall.
    // mFacebook.authorize(this, new PostDialogListener());

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    //parameters.putString("message", "Some message");// the message to post
    parameters.putString("app_id", "my_id");
    parameters.putString("caption", "some caption");
    parameters.putString("description", "some description");
                                                    // to the wall
    mFacebook.dialog(GameActivity.this, "feed", parameters,
            new PostDialogListener());// "stream.publish" is an API call
    // mFacebook.dialog(this, "feed", new PostDialogListener());
}
```

This is not working. I am not able to set a pre populated message inside the dialog box that is showing up. How do I go about this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: webnetmobile is right. Nobody wants to be 70 th :)

Comment: it would be better if you could answer the questions. I will respect the internet community by making more accepts. All I have to do is go in get more ticks up - which I will do. But I request you answer me if you know then answer.

Answer (score 2):

The message parameter will be ignored. By Facebook policy, you cannot pre-populate this field. Only the user can be the one that sets the message.